Can I use Vico in a java project?
I found this library for making charts in android called Vico. (https://github.com/patrykandpatrick/vico)
I was wondering if it is possible to use it inside of a java project.
This is the kotlin usage:
At the top level of the Activity:
val modelProducer = CartesianChartModelProducer()

In onCreate:
cartesianChartView.modelProducer = modelProducer
lifecycleScope.launch {
modelProducer.runTransaction { columnSeries { series(4, 12, 8, 16) } }
>  }

Because I am not using Jetpack Compose, I have only added this to by dependencies:
implementation("com.patrykandpatrick.vico:views:2.0.0-beta.3")
The following code I have tried:
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   cartesianChartView = view.findViewById(R.id.cartesian_chart_view);
   CartesianChartModelProducer modelProducer = new CartesianChartModelProducer();

   cartesianChartView.setModelProducer(modelProducer);

   // No idea here
   modelProducer.runTransaction()
}

Yet I am not sure how to continue with the runTransaction. I am not sure where "columnSeries" and "series" comes from and how to use it.

If you mean a Java project for Android-  yes.  Kotlin can call Java code and Java code can call Kotlin code

Yet do I need to add kotlin into my project somehow? I can't seem to call columnSeries not sure if it's part of the library or kotlin
